# Navigation between Inner published folder Applications

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, web-hosting, iis-8

I have a one doubt about hosting the nested publish folders.

Now I have a one published (project A) folder. And then published (Project B) folder in to the project A 's published folder.

Then I hosted the project A's folder in IIS server.

Now how can I access the application for project B 's published folder from the hosted project A.

Is this possible? Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want to access the nested web api application directly. You may face the 404 or 500 error, since the route setting is not right. Here is a workaround You could set a nested web application for the web site A in IIS. Then you could access the web siteB.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open IIS management console， right click the web site and select the add web application

[image]

2.Select the right physical path:

[image]